# MVC Alternative to iframe

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, iframe, partial-views

I'm looking for an alternative to using an IFRAME to load a full page within a wrapper page all pages using MVC3. I need the wrapper page for centralized login and authentication and would like to load other pages dynamically within a section of the wrapper sort of like loading a module within WPF. I have previously used an IFRAME to accomplish this but I would like to keep navigation intact (ie the back button would go to the previously loaded "plugin" page instead of the wrappers previous page). I thought I might be able to accomplish this with partial views but have not been able to find a way to load a partial view from a completely distinct project (or from an already hosted site). Any ideas?

Comment: If loading content from a completely different/external site, IFRAME is just about your only option...

Comment: Thanks, I think I will have to continue to use an IFRAME.. I'm wondering if I can catch the back button action with javascript and redirect to a different page..

Answer (score 4):

You can make an ajax call to get the contents from the external site and put them at the required place in your parent page html. This you can do onload of the page.

using jquery, it will be something like:

```
$.ajax({
        url: 'http://www.externalsite.com',
        cache: false,
        dataType: "html",
        success: function (data) {
           $("#divInsideParentPage").html(data);
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [this page](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/07/02/introducing-razor.aspx) under the heading "Layout/MasterPage Scenarios – The Basics"

In short, you create a master template and insert placeholders for where your content will appear...

How exactly it works depends on the view engine you're using (Razor, etc...)

EDIT:

WRT History/Back button, you may be able to use [history.js](https://github.com/balupton/History.js/) to achieve what you want. See [this site](http://spotlight-publishing.co.uk/) which uses it extensively (it loads content using AJAX - The base page is never changed after the initial load).

Comment: Yeah that works for pages of the same project, I need to load completely pages from a different or external site.

Comment: Apologies, I mis-read your Q. You've got 2 options, Ajax as proposed by @VishalKumar or download the page server-side and serve it with your template. I'd personally suggest the AJAX option as a) it doesn't use your bandwidth and b) You can never be tricked into being an anonymising relay for someone else. See my edit for a suggestion re: history